# How to avoid Flex application store temporary internet files?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds, browser-cache, temporary-files

I'm Fran.

I've programmed a Java application using BlazeDS and Flex, but i think the problem also occurs in any ajax style application.

It's a monitoring application, so requests are made regularly to the server. The browser has stored a large amount of temporary internet files on the client pc even getting it saturated.

How I can avoid this?

I have seen some articles that say to include variables in the html header as:

- Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=-1
- Pragma: no-cache, no-store
- Expires: -1

but does not work.

Please I need help.

Comment: AMF calls to BlazeDS are being cached?

Comment: What exactly is being cached in temporary internet files?

Answer (score 0):

If in order to monitoring application you use HTTP then inside Flex application:

```
//your server side application url
const MY_APPLICATION_URL = "http://google.com/";

//construct url for each request
private function _getRequsetUrl():String
{
    return MY_APPLICATION_URL + "?_=" + new Date().getTime().toString();
}

//load response of server side application
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
request.url = _getRequestUrl();

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.load(request);

//or
var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
service.url = _getRequestUrl();
service.send();
```

Comment: Hi Kostik, Thank for your response.

Comment: I think my problem is not that.

 The browser stores large amount of information in Windows folder C: / Documents and Settings / User / Local Settings / Temporary Internet Files.

 In this folder there is only information of my Flex application like .swf, history, .js, .html but actually accessing the properties of the folder size does not correspond to the generated files.

 I don't understand what is happening. When I open my flex application in browser and remains open one hour can create 108 MB of disk capacity

Comment: I not think that this is related with Flex/Flash Player :)
At this folder located hidden system directories of Internet Explorer